# Clarification to proposition about limit points

Tags: general-topology, limits, proof-verification, proof-explanation

In Topology without Tears I have Proposition 3.1.6.:

[image: Proposition 3.1.6]

The author talks about points belonging to a set. I am not entirely sure what he means by that, thus I would like to have some clarification regarding it.

Here is the to me ambiguous part of the proof:

[image: Part 1 of the Proof]

If I may reword it:

For $A$ closed in $(X, \tau)$, $p$ limit point of $A$ and $p \in A$ - nothing to show.

Now let $A$ be closed in $(X, \tau)$, $p$ limit point of $A$ and $p \notin A$:

$ \Rightarrow p \in X\backslash A $ open $ \Rightarrow ( X\backslash A)\cap A = \emptyset => p$  not a limit point. Contradiction.

Comment: A possible source of confusion is that the wording of the proof may lead the reader to believe that $p$ is the point that is both in $A$ and $X \setminus A$ and that causes the contradiction.  Instead, the definition of limit point says that $(X \setminus A) \setminus \{p\}$ has non-empty intersection with $A$.  Since $(X \setminus A) \setminus \{p\}$ is a subset of $(X \setminus A)$, the contradiction follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't follow your links, but hopefully I can clarify your reworded point of contention. I assume the definition of limit point you're working with is that $p$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if given any open set $U$ with $p \in U$, then $A \cap (U \setminus \{p\}) \neq \varnothing$. Is this correct? If so, then notice that you could choose $X\setminus A = U$ to find an open set for which the above definition does not hold.

Comment: Yeah, I started thinking with this definition and became insecure as suddenly I were not sure, what "point belongs to set" exactly means. Your post however seems to affirm my clarification, which makes me quite happy. I will accept the answer in 4mins.